# Superfish problem in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, superfish

I'm having issues with my Superfish third level menu items, it works fine in everything other than IE6!

You can view it here;
http://christhrower.com/newWork/Farhi

The sub-sub nav doesn't pop up in IE6.

Anybody have any ideas on this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I has a similar problem with this years ago. My solution was to add an extra style="width:xx" into the div for that menu section which seemed to fix it for IE6.  Dont know if its the same problem you are having but might be wirth a try.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to reply - this seems to have fixed the problem